# SignalR HubProxy.Invoke Thread Safety

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, signalr

My (.Net) SignalR client is a multi-threaded application, can I reuse one IHubProxy in all the client application threads? or do I need to synchronize the calls to IHubProxy.Invoke?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SignalR's `HubProxy` (and by extension `HubConnection` and `Connection`) should be thread-safe. In fact, if you call `HubConnection.CreateHubProxy` multiple times with the same `hubName`, you should get the same cached `IHubProxy` object anyway.

If you find any issues using an `IHubProxy` in non-synchronized code, [please report an issue](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues).

Comment: Seems like you're right, it's a shame though that the documentation says the opposite: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.hubproxy(v=vs.111).aspx